# "Almost" answered question with a bounty

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Four days ago I asked a question on MSE that had zero replies till I opened a 50 rep. bounty on it (now it has only one) ...well now a user gave me rich answer with examples and stuff..but it fill only 3 points of my question:

the first point (and the main) was about references, general name (and specific of that case) of the object that I described but he gave me only a link to the "operator" page on wiki, there I'm totally lost in a new (for me) huge field of mathematics and I cant find the references on my own.

The question is about some sets of real valued functions and an operator on them

> [Sets $f_n\in A_f$ where $f_{n+1}=f_n \circ S \circ f^{\circ (-1)}_n$ and operator $\alpha(f_n)=f_{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360358/sets-f-n-in-a-f-where-f-n1-f-n-circ-s-circ-f-circ-1-n-and-operato)

Before the reply of the user i didn't know the name of the object.

I'm very intrested and before spending lot of my time on it discovering already known things I wanted to find is this special operator $\alpha$.

Seems me this question is'nt very intresting since i can still have the wanted information.

What Should I do?

1)Is better if I wait a bit?

2)or maybe update\improve the question asking more about this in terms of operators and functional analisis?

3)or give that bounty away, and create a new question with only the first question (that is already in this question).

Since seems me that ppl aren't very intrested in the topic of my question the option 3) is like wasting time with a useless "duplicate"?

thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I would opt for 3). Generally a question should contain only one major question and not several of them.

Comment: You have to physically "give" a bounty. If you do not give it then only half will go to the person with the most votes (or the accepted answer, I cannot remember, but it is a moot point in this case). The rest will disappear.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker so I can give him the bounty, don't accept any answer and create a more specific question with a reference to my first one?

Comment: You can also accept an answer and create a new question.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker followed your tip and was the best thing to do , thanks New question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380139/has-this-operator-a-name-alpha-gf-g-ominus-f-f-circ-g-circ-f-circ-1